# flask python list to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am using python flask temple to build a site. I have a case where I want to send a python list to a java script. The python list contains three objects however when I do list1.length in the java script environment I see the length of this list is 23. This is most likely because java script is identifying it as a string. My question is how to make the python list stay a list once it's passed into javascript ?

```
# my route with python list1
@app.route('/chart_sandbox')
def chart_sandbox():

    list1 = ['abc', 'def', 'hij']

    return render_template("chart_sandbox.html", list1=json.dumps(list1))




# My Java script
<script type="text/javascript">

    var list1 = '{{list1|tojson}}'
    var listLength = list1.length


    document.write(listLength)
    document.write(list1)

</script>

# this is what is returned to me. As you can see java script length is seen 
#as 23 instead of 3
23"["abc", "def", "hij"]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the jinja text. That's converting your list into a string-representation of a list. Something like this should work:

```
var list1 = {{ list1 | tojson }};
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that did not work. I just got two less characters returned as it seems it was counting the quote marks as well. My return output was changed from 23 to 21 :return outout>>>>> 21["abc", "def", "hij"]

Comment: If it's a JSON string, parse it with `JSON.parse()` (in Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

This worked me,
I wrapped the list with the or operation and tojson in double curly brackets as an argument in the JSON.parse function, to make it a JavaScript object.

```
let list1 = JSON.parse('{{ list1 | tojson }}');
```

If you have no plans to modify the data in JavaScript use this instead

```
const list1 = JSON.parse('{{ list1 | tojson }}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,it works for me.

```
<script>
  var divlist = {{ pylist | tojson }};
  for(i=0; i < divlist.length; i++){
       divId = divlist[i];
       console.log(divId);
   }
</script>
```